# 'csc' command is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, windows-8.1

To run a simple program I was using 'csc' in command prompt and it was working fine. Please advice on below both issues

a) But after installing IIS in my laptop now it is not working.

b) And even if I try with Visual Studio Development Server for a web application it is showing error 500. Don't know if both issues are inter-related.

Below are the few steps which I did:

- Installation of IIS
- c:\Windows\Microsoft .Net\v4.0\csc.exe, which showing below error::

  Warning: No source file specified
  error CS1562: Outputs without source must have the /out option specified

Thanks!

Comment: That error says that you didn't give it any files to compile.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch No I am giving file.It is working in VS command prompt but not working in normal Command prompt.Can you please advice me on (b) Issue[Error 500] also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csc need something to go on as can be seen from the information that microsoft privides on the usage of csc:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

So it is still working fine you need to feed the compiler with input. It needs your cs files as input and perhaps even some other parameters to specify the output filename and such.

csc File.cs : compiles the File.cs source file and creates a File.exe

Comment: Actually I am giving input file.I am running this in Command Prompt not in VS Command Prompt. And Can you please advise me on (b) Issue [Error 500] also.

Comment: then show your exact command, how on earth were we supposed to know if you don't tell. The warning is related to not passing a file.